# How to Display JSONObject in Android?

Tags: android, json

I just requested a JSONObject from an URL and I wonder two things.
Is a JSONObject like a JSONArray, or not? Which should I request?
And is there a way to display this JSONObject somehow like `var_dump` in PHP?
Just to check whether it worked?

Help is much appreciated!
Philip

Comment: `Is a JSONObject like a JSONArray, or not?` => start here: json.org. `Which should I request?` depends on what you are requesting and what you are going to do with it. `display this JSONObject`-> Read doc for JSONObject.toString();

Answer (score 6):

1. [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) is different from a [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)
2. Just to ckeck you can invoke `.toString()` on your JSONObject (or JSONArray) instance.

   JSONObject jo = ...

   Log.d("TAG", jo.toString());

Answer (score 3):

JSONArray is an array of JSONObjects. A JSONObject can hold one or more JSONArrays. Generally you pull a single JSONObject root node and break it up from there.

You can print the JSON by using `[JSONObject#toString()][1]`.  You can also use `JSONObject#toString(int indentSpaces)` to put it in a more readable form like so:

```
 {
     "query": "Pizza",
     "locations": [
         94043,
         90210
     ]
 }
```